# Is it possible to modify command line parameters programmatically in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I'm working with some legacy code that uses `ParamCount()` and `ParamStr()` in various places, and now I need to provide different values than those that were actually passed as command line variables.

The simplest solution would be to programmatically add/modify the existing command line parameters, since the alternative is to change A LOT of the legacy code to accept function parameters rather than directly accessing `ParamCount()` and `ParamStr()`.

Is this possible? Can I somehow add/modify parameters from within the program itself so that `ParamCount()` `ParamStr()` will pick up my new/modified parameters?

> Edit, clarification of the legacy code:
>
> The legacy code makes some database requests, using `where` arguments from the command line (and sanitizing them). This is fine in 99.9% of all cases, as these arguments are fundamental for the purpose of the legacy units. However, I'm working on a new feature that "breaks the mold", where one of these fundamental arguments are unknown and need to be fetched from the database and provided internally.
>
> Yes, I could search and replace, but my objective here is to not touch the legacy code, as it's in a unit that is shared among many different programs.
>
> Restarting the program and/or executing a new copy of it from itself is one solution, but seems a bit risky and cumbersome. This is a production program that executes on a server and needs to be as simple and robust as possible.

Comment: You could create a unit with two functions named `ParamCount` and `ParamStr` with the same signatures as the RTL functions, and then include this unit at the end of each implementation section `uses` list in your legacy application.

Comment: A very low-tech tip, but perhaps use Notepad++ or some other utility that can Search & Replace through multiple files at once? ParamCount and ParamStr are likely to be unique enough for this to work. Search for them and replace with your own new variable names.

Comment: Restarting application with modified parameters could be a solution.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand that would require recompiling the legacy code to break its dependancy on the `ParamCount()` and `ParamStr()` functions of the `SysUtils` unit.  It sounds like the OP does not work to do that, as there is a lot of code that would have to be changed, and the code in question is shared by multiple programs.  He just wants to make the `SysUtils` functions return different values as needed.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible? Can I somehow add/modify parameters from within the program itself so that ParamCount() ParamStr() will pick up my new/modified parameters?

*Technically yes*, but it is not something that the RTL itself exposes functionality for, so you will have to implement it manually.

Since you are working with legacy code, I'm assuming you are working on Windows only.  In which case, `ParamStr()` and `ParamCount()` parse the string returned by the Win32 API [`GetCommandLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinea) function in `kernel32.dll`.

So, one option is to simply hook the `GetCommandLine()` function itself at runtime, such as with Microsoft's [Detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/), or other similar library.  Then your hook can return whatever string you want <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1: for that matter, you could just hook `ParamCount()` and `ParamStr()` instead, and make them return whatever you want.</sup>

Another option - which requires messing around with lower-level memory that you don't own, and I don't advise doing this - is to obtain a pointer to the [`PEB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-peb) structure of the calling process.  You can obtain that pointer using [`NTQueryInformationProcess(ProcessBasicInformation)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess).  The `PEB` contains a `ProcessParameters` field, which is a pointer to an [`RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-rtl_user_process_parameters) struct, which contains the actual `CommandLine` string as a [`UNICODE_STRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/subauth/ns-subauth-unicode_string) struct.  If your altered string is less then, or equal to, the length of the original command line string, you can just alter the content of the `ProcessParameters.CommandLine` in-place.  Otherwise, you would have to allocate new memory to hold your altered string and then update `ProcessParameters.CommandLine` to point at that new memory.